# Mocking NHibernate & Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, testing, mocking

I'm using NHibernate and exposed the Session in my front end. I have a controller action which retrieves tasks as follows:

```
public ActionResult Overview(DateTime date)
{
    var allTasks = GetTasksUpUntilDate(date);
    return PartialView("Tasks/Overview", allTasks);
}

private List<TaskOverviewModel> GetTasksUpUntilDate(DateTime date)
{            
    var allTasks = _session.Query<Task>().Where(t.BookedBy.UserName.Equals(CurrentUser.Name,
                                       StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));            
    var tasks = allTasks.Where(t => t.DueDate <= date);

    var taskVMs = new List<TaskOverviewModel>();        
    tasks.ForEach(t => taskVMs.Add(MapEntityToViewModel(t)));

    return taskVMs;
}
```

Now I don't want to create an IRepository just for my views since ISession actually already is a repository. Mocking/stubbing this however is proving rather hard. So can anyone help me to have _session.Query return a list of objects I provide while testing?.

I'd also like to avoid setting up an in memory database and am using RhinoMocks for my tests.

Answer (score 5):

Dont fake Nh/linq. Instead setup an in-memory sqlite db to query against. They are extremely fast and easy to use.

Comment: A +1 but it comes with a link from one of the greats - http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing

Comment: Sorry, that post was a little outdated, this setup worked for us - http://ayende.com/blog/1772/unit-testing-with-nhibernate-active-record

Comment: By doing this, you have an integration test. I.e. you are testing more than just business logic. You are also 'testing' nnib. And how it fetches data.

Comment: This becomes a symantic debate. I will leave it that the query is part of the logic and should be tested as such.

Comment: Having tried to mock NHibernate 3 (IQueryOver, IQuery etc.), I found you end up writing more  or less the same LOC for the mocks as the actual production code. So yes, use SQLite/CE and if required abstract away the NH stuff into set of repositories or services or you'll find it untestable with Moq/Rhino etc.

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate Session might fit the repository pattern, but if you are building your controllers to talk to it directly, you are not truly abstracting it. Mocking it when you aren't abstracting it is not a reliable solution.

If you absolutely don't want to abstract it (which is pure lazy, IMO), then the sqllite db as mentioned by Jason is a good call. However, on a large project properly separating your concerns is very much a good idea.

My domain model contains the interfaces for both the data access objects (repos) and the services which consume them. This allows me to truly separate my data concerns from my business concerns, which *should* be entirely separated from the view/app concerns. This allows proper unit testing and the ability to easily swap out parts or do proper mocking.

Each layer ONLY talks to interfaces, NEVER to an implementation. Furthermore my application layer never talks directly to the data layer - only services. Allowing that to happen seems to encourage developers to be lazy and start putting business or data logic into the application.

Comment: +1. Using an OR/M in the controller is plain wrong. I wish that I could ask the OP one year from now how easy it is to maintain the application. The responsibility of the controller is to be a glue between the domain model and the view, not to be the domain model.

Comment: ISession is the abstraction. abstracting the abstraction only complicates the solution and doesn't provide any direct value.

Comment: Isession is an abstraction for nh *only*, not data access. Abstracting data access is *very* useful.

Comment: The session being used in the controller is only for view access, writes are being done through a whole different infrastructure. Hence using the session is perfectly viable in this case. Jason Meckley is quite right saying that abstracting the abstraction does not provide value, you just lose features of your ORM.

Comment: Mirage, yousaid it much better than me:)

Comment: So you guys are saying its totally a good idea to tightly couple your application's controllers to a specific data access technology? Sorry, can't agree with that.

Comment: @Jason Meckley, ISession is a very leaky abstraction. If it was a good abstraction it would be easy to mock out.